# Python encrypting using hmac and sha256 isn't giving the same results as javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json, encryption

I am trying to get the same results in python and javascript but when the in encryption I am having troubles, the encryption gave me the same result in javascript and in python but if I put the data in json format and then encrypt I get different results.I can change the javascript code because is for an api the python code can be modified if it is needed.
Python code:

```py
from datetime import datetime
import json
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

s="2017-12-11 23:31:55"
data1=dict(timestamp=s)
msg_data = json.dumps(data1)

print msg_data

message = bytes(s).encode('utf-8')
secret = bytes("secret").encode('utf-8')
msg_data2 = bytes(msg_data).encode('utf-8')

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, message, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
print "without json"
print(signature)    #XZqVjDKYG8NRITjiMNXFZnNdUDb+JIr7Vm+f3CabETY=

signature = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(secret, msg_data2, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())
print "with json"
print(signature)    #RnxbwptM7HuEE1SPResxc4A6tVDqhv3DxWP75g8pfik=
```

JS code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkiss/crypto-js/master/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/hmac-sha256.js
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
var CryptoJS=CryptoJS||function(h,s){var f={},g=f.lib={},q=function(){},m=g.Base={extend:function(a){q.prototype=this;var c=new q;a&&c.mixIn(a);c.hasOwnProperty("init")||(c.init=function(){c.$super.init.apply(this,arguments)});c.init.prototype=c;c.$super=this;return c},create:function(){var a=this.extend();a.init.apply(a,arguments);return a},init:function(){},mixIn:function(a){for(var c in a)a.hasOwnProperty(c)&&(this[c]=a[c]);a.hasOwnProperty("toString")&&(this.toString=a.toString)},clone:function(){return this.init.prototype.extend(this)}},
r=g.WordArray=m.extend({init:function(a,c){a=this.words=a||[];this.sigBytes=c!=s?c:4*a.length},toString:function(a){return(a||k).stringify(this)},concat:function(a){var c=this.words,d=a.words,b=this.sigBytes;a=a.sigBytes;this.clamp();if(b%4)for(var e=0;e<a;e++)c[b+e>>>2]|=(d[e>>>2]>>>24-8*(e%4)&255)<<24-8*((b+e)%4);else if(65535<d.length)for(e=0;e<a;e+=4)c[b+e>>>2]=d[e>>>2];else c.push.apply(c,d);this.sigBytes+=a;return this},clamp:function(){var a=this.words,c=this.sigBytes;a[c>>>2]&=4294967295<<
32-8*(c%4);a.length=h.ceil(c/4)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);a.words=this.words.slice(0);return a},random:function(a){for(var c=[],d=0;d<a;d+=4)c.push(4294967296*h.random()|0);return new r.init(c,a)}}),l=f.enc={},k=l.Hex={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++){var e=c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255;d.push((e>>>4).toString(16));d.push((e&15).toString(16))}return d.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b+=2)d[b>>>3]|=parseInt(a.substr(b,
2),16)<<24-4*(b%8);return new r.init(d,c/2)}},n=l.Latin1={stringify:function(a){var c=a.words;a=a.sigBytes;for(var d=[],b=0;b<a;b++)d.push(String.fromCharCode(c[b>>>2]>>>24-8*(b%4)&255));return d.join("")},parse:function(a){for(var c=a.length,d=[],b=0;b<c;b++)d[b>>>2]|=(a.charCodeAt(b)&255)<<24-8*(b%4);return new r.init(d,c)}},j=l.Utf8={stringify:function(a){try{return decodeURIComponent(escape(n.stringify(a)))}catch(c){throw Error("Malformed UTF-8 data");}},parse:function(a){return n.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(a)))}},
u=g.BufferedBlockAlgorithm=m.extend({reset:function(){this._data=new r.init;this._nDataBytes=0},_append:function(a){"string"==typeof a&&(a=j.parse(a));this._data.concat(a);this._nDataBytes+=a.sigBytes},_process:function(a){var c=this._data,d=c.words,b=c.sigBytes,e=this.blockSize,f=b/(4*e),f=a?h.ceil(f):h.max((f|0)-this._minBufferSize,0);a=f*e;b=h.min(4*a,b);if(a){for(var g=0;g<a;g+=e)this._doProcessBlock(d,g);g=d.splice(0,a);c.sigBytes-=b}return new r.init(g,b)},clone:function(){var a=m.clone.call(this);
a._data=this._data.clone();return a},_minBufferSize:0});g.Hasher=u.extend({cfg:m.extend(),init:function(a){this.cfg=this.cfg.extend(a);this.reset()},reset:function(){u.reset.call(this);this._doReset()},update:function(a){this._append(a);this._process();return this},finalize:function(a){a&&this._append(a);return this._doFinalize()},blockSize:16,_createHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new a.init(d)).finalize(c)}},_createHmacHelper:function(a){return function(c,d){return(new t.HMAC.init(a,
d)).finalize(c)}}});var t=f.algo={};return f}(Math);
(function(h){for(var s=CryptoJS,f=s.lib,g=f.WordArray,q=f.Hasher,f=s.algo,m=[],r=[],l=function(a){return 4294967296*(a-(a|0))|0},k=2,n=0;64>n;){var j;a:{j=k;for(var u=h.sqrt(j),t=2;t<=u;t++)if(!(j%t)){j=!1;break a}j=!0}j&&(8>n&&(m[n]=l(h.pow(k,0.5))),r[n]=l(h.pow(k,1/3)),n++);k++}var a=[],f=f.SHA256=q.extend({_doReset:function(){this._hash=new g.init(m.slice(0))},_doProcessBlock:function(c,d){for(var b=this._hash.words,e=b[0],f=b[1],g=b[2],j=b[3],h=b[4],m=b[5],n=b[6],q=b[7],p=0;64>p;p++){if(16>p)a[p]=
c[d+p]|0;else{var k=a[p-15],l=a[p-2];a[p]=((k<<25|k>>>7)^(k<<14|k>>>18)^k>>>3)+a[p-7]+((l<<15|l>>>17)^(l<<13|l>>>19)^l>>>10)+a[p-16]}k=q+((h<<26|h>>>6)^(h<<21|h>>>11)^(h<<7|h>>>25))+(h&m^~h&n)+r[p]+a[p];l=((e<<30|e>>>2)^(e<<19|e>>>13)^(e<<10|e>>>22))+(e&f^e&g^f&g);q=n;n=m;m=h;h=j+k|0;j=g;g=f;f=e;e=k+l|0}b[0]=b[0]+e|0;b[1]=b[1]+f|0;b[2]=b[2]+g|0;b[3]=b[3]+j|0;b[4]=b[4]+h|0;b[5]=b[5]+m|0;b[6]=b[6]+n|0;b[7]=b[7]+q|0},_doFinalize:function(){var a=this._data,d=a.words,b=8*this._nDataBytes,e=8*a.sigBytes;
d[e>>>5]|=128<<24-e%32;d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+14]=h.floor(b/4294967296);d[(e+64>>>9<<4)+15]=b;a.sigBytes=4*d.length;this._process();return this._hash},clone:function(){var a=q.clone.call(this);a._hash=this._hash.clone();return a}});s.SHA256=q._createHelper(f);s.HmacSHA256=q._createHmacHelper(f)})(Math);
(function(){var h=CryptoJS,s=h.enc.Utf8;h.algo.HMAC=h.lib.Base.extend({init:function(f,g){f=this._hasher=new f.init;"string"==typeof g&&(g=s.parse(g));var h=f.blockSize,m=4*h;g.sigBytes>m&&(g=f.finalize(g));g.clamp();for(var r=this._oKey=g.clone(),l=this._iKey=g.clone(),k=r.words,n=l.words,j=0;j<h;j++)k[j]^=1549556828,n[j]^=909522486;r.sigBytes=l.sigBytes=m;this.reset()},reset:function(){var f=this._hasher;f.reset();f.update(this._iKey)},update:function(f){this._hasher.update(f);return this},finalize:function(f){var g=
this._hasher;f=g.finalize(f);g.reset();return g.finalize(this._oKey.clone().concat(f))}})})();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*
     https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jkiss/crypto-js/master/tags/3.1.2/build/components/enc-base64-min.js
CryptoJS v3.1.2
code.google.com/p/crypto-js
(c) 2009-2013 by Jeff Mott. All rights reserved.
code.google.com/p/crypto-js/wiki/License
*/
(function(){var h=CryptoJS,j=h.lib.WordArray;h.enc.Base64={stringify:function(b){var e=b.words,f=b.sigBytes,c=this._map;b.clamp();b=[];for(var a=0;a<f;a+=3)for(var d=(e[a>>>2]>>>24-8*(a%4)&255)<<16|(e[a+1>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+1)%4)&255)<<8|e[a+2>>>2]>>>24-8*((a+2)%4)&255,g=0;4>g&&a+0.75*g<f;g++)b.push(c.charAt(d>>>6*(3-g)&63));if(e=c.charAt(64))for(;b.length%4;)b.push(e);return b.join("")},parse:function(b){var e=b.length,f=this._map,c=f.charAt(64);c&&(c=b.indexOf(c),-1!=c&&(e=c));for(var c=[],a=0,d=0;d<e;d++)if(d%4){var g=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d-1))<<2*(d%4),h=f.indexOf(b.charAt(d))>>>6-2*(d%4);c[a>>>2]|=(g|h)<<24-8*(a%4);a++}return j.create(c,a)},_map:"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="}})();
</script>


<script>
  var secret="secret"




  data_time= '2017' + '-' + '12' + '-' + '11' + ' '  + '23' + ':' + '31' + ':' + '55';

  //params.content['timestamp'] = '2017' + '-' + '12' + '-' + '11' + ' '
  //                            + '23' + ':' + '31' + ':' + '55';

  var json = JSON.stringify({"timestamp":"2017-12-11 23:31:55"});
  console.log(json);

  var data1=CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(data_time,secret));
  console.log("Without json:");
  console.log(data1);//XZqVjDKYG8NRITjiMNXFZnNdUDb+JIr7Vm+f3CabETY=



  var data2=CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(json,secret));
  console.log("With json:");

  console.log(data2);//s5q78/m3wIb518O8M9x1rAM2DvG/I+Vmt0rBtb6LYS8=
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`msg_data` from the python and `json` from the javascript are likely slightly different.

`msg_data` from the python:

```
{"timestamp": "2017-12-11 23:31:55"}
```

`json` from the javascript:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-12-11 23:31:55"}
```

Use the optional [`separator` argument to `json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#basic-usage) to remove the default space after each:

```
msg_data = json.dumps(data1, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Answer (score 2):

You're hashing different data.

In the Python version, `msg_data` is:

```
{"timestamp": "2017-12-11 23:31:55"}
            ^^^
```

In the Javascript version, `json` is:

```
{"timestamp":"2017-12-11 23:31:55"}
            ^^
```

Note that there's no space after `"timestamp":` in the JS version. Not all JSON implementations will generate the exact same output for the same data. (You'll run into more problems when there's more than one key in the dictionary -- JSON doesn't set any requirements on what order the keys appear in.)